# How to use mock in support of UI development?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, mocking, javafx-2, ui-testing

I m working on a user interface in JavaFX. It is the front-end of an infrastructure service that I have already developed and is operational. I read here and there that mock can be used to avoid running all the system when it is to heavy to run, but also for isolation purpose.

At present I want to run some basic test as I am also learning how to use JavaFX and I would not want to run all my infrastructure for the matter.

Basically I have a `TreeView` that I would like to update based on what is coming from the service. Normally the service that runs in background would update the model and call a `Platform.runlater()` method to ask the UI to refresh.

I was wondering how can I achieve that using mocking. How can I have a mock object update a simplified shared structure such as a list(model) and then call `Platform.runlater()`? Actually I would first ask: is it a possible and appropriate usage of mock and if yes how can it be done, with which framework?

Personally what is a bit not clear to me is the involvement of multi-threading. Indeed my object under test which is the interface would not be calling any method of my mock, expect indirectly, the `Run()` method, given that my service is a runnable.

Hence I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me a bit further on the matter. I'm confused....

Best,

Maatari

Answer (score 0):

First prepare applications (or change your current app to support test mode) which can populate your TreeView with specific data. The entity which will provide fake data for TreeView will be your **mock** object for specific data. It should look like a service from TreeView point of view, which means you need to extract common methods from your services class into interface and make TreeView use this interface instead of concrete class.

To handle UI testing you can you use [JemmyFX](https://jemmy.java.net/JemmyFXGuide/jemmy-guide.html#inst) library. You can create simple test which will verify any UI properties of your TestView or imitate user actions like mouse clicks or text input. You may not worry about threading issues, jemmy will handle it for you.

It can look next way (I use junit as test harness here):

```
public class TreeTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        // running your specially crafted FX application with mock service data
        // you can do it any way, e.g. by calling main() method with some parameters
        AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(TreeApp.class);
    }

   @Test // this is junit annotation for test
   public void fooTest() {
        // here we are receiving special jemmyfx entity which knows how to handle 
        // tree views and is attached to your TreeView
        // (if you app has only one TreeView, you may need additional logic for several ones)
        TreeViewDock tree = new TreeViewDock(new SceneDock().asParent());
        // this way we can find some item which you expected to see in you TreeView 
        // because you've created you mock data this way.
        // Note that underlying code will respect UI threading, 
        // will understand that UI can have delay and will give it certain time without blocking
        // and will throw descriptive exception in case expected item wasn't found
        tree.asTree().selector().select(new ByToStringLookup("item1"));

        // you can find subitems
        tree.asTree().selector().select(new ByToStringLookup("item1"), new ByToStringLookup("subitem1");
        // and perform operations on them, e.g. expand:
        new TreeItemDock(tree.asItemParent(), new EqualsLookup("item2")).asTreeItem().expand();
        //etc
    }
```

You can find more info on site on just by code completion hints

Comment: Thanks, looking into it